# how do I change my program languages in VS?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I would like to know how to change my program languages in visual Studio.
I started to learn C and I want to run C codes from VS, but when I installed the app I didn't choose C to install it. Does someone know how to change my languages in VS?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Visual Studio Installer to change the installation and add additional workloads. I think this is what you are looking for (click on modify to get here):

[image: Visual Studio Installer]

Comment: Yes but I already installed the VS and I removed the VS installer from the downloads :(